# Show posts without content in RSS 2 FEED

Tags: rss, feed

Those posts that do not have a content, do not show up inside my feed via the URL.
I want all of them to show up, even the ones without content.

How ?

Comment: Does this happen with the default theme installed and no plugins? I can't reproduce this behavoiur ...

Comment: i have some plugins. but the theme is the default theme.

Comment: I wrote a post with some title and no content and pressed publish, it shows up both here `http://example.com/feed/` and here `http://example.com/?feed=rss2` - tested on TwentyTwelve and TwentyThirteen.

Comment: weird.... does this mean a plugin is causing the issue ?

Comment: could be or you are viewing a cached version of your feed in your browser?

Comment: @birgire, I dont think so... as other posts (added recently to test) are showing.

Comment: @birgire, indeed the issue was from a plugin I was using, and it was resolved via its settings. thanks a lot for the tip :)

Comment: it's great to hear you solved the problem